# How can I initialize each web test in a Visual Studio load test

Tags: visual-studio-2015, load-testing

I have a Visul Studio load test which contains one web test. The web test does the following:

1. Go to start page
2. Login
3. Go to page City
4. Go to page Customer
5. Logout

The load test runs with a constant load of 100 users.

I want to change my load test with an log in initialization so that the web test does the following:

1. Go to page City
2. Sleep for 5 seconds
3. Go to page Customer
4. Sleep for 5 seconds

Given the circumstance that the user is already logged in during some sort of initialization.

Can this be done? Any help appreciated.
Drutten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test mix of the scenario has the facility to `Select an initialize test to execute before other tests for each virtual user`. You can create a web test that just does a login. The context (right click) menu of the scenario has an `Edit test mix` command.

The test mix can also specify a termination test for the virtual users.